# Why my texture becomes black in certain regions?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I'm trying to implement some kind of *Ian Hubert* style. I use a PBR texture for the wall, mixed a brick PBR texture with a moss PBR texture and used some other image textures for the windows and such. As you can see in the following image, the texture gets black for whatever reason:

[image]

[image]

The same thing happens in the viewport preview (it's a different version of the scene):

[image]

How do I mix the textures:

[image]

As you can see the texture becomes black at a certain angle. The blend mode is set to *opaque*:

[image]

[image]

Interestingly, there is no issue when using Eevee:

[image]

I don't get why is this is happening and what I can do to get rid of those artefacts. Can you guys please give me any advice or ideally some suggestions how to fix this in cycles?

Comment: Ummm, where does the texture get black?

Comment: hello, maybe show some screenshots of your node setup, it's hard to guess without it

Comment: Blending mode would only be related here if you were trying to render image with transparency since it controls how transparent parts of textures are rendered if at all. It looks in your case like improper rendering of bump/normal map. Unfortunately node setup isn't visible since nodes're too small

Comment: Agree with MrZak. Recommend add a better screenshot of your nodes in order to get help, otherwise it's just guessing what the issue is...

Answer (score 1):

in case several textures are overlaying - I assume the green parts contain an alpha channel - have you enabled the Blend-Value within the Render-Settings?
[image: Screen shows the Blend-Value of a material setting]

Comment: i have enabled the blend mode to opaque and shadow mode but it's not solving the issue